# Regular expression not working on if statement

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'am using following regex to pull several information from a file.

```
def inventory():
    with open('inventory.log', 'r+') as f:
        match_hostname = re.compile(r'NAME: "(.+)",')
        match_pid = re.compile(r'PID: (.+) ,')
        match_sn = re.compile(r'SN: (.+)')
        list_text = [text.strip() for text in f]
        for line in list_text:
            match_regex_hostname = match_hostname.search(line)
            match_regex_pid = match_pid.search(line)
            match_regex_sn = match_sn.search(line)
            if match_regex_hostname:
                final_hostname = match_regex_hostname.group(1).strip(" ")
                print final_hostname
            elif match_regex_pid:
                final_pid = match_regex_pid.group(1).strip(" ")
                print final_pid
            elif match_regex_sn:
                final_sn = match_regex_sn.group(1).strip(" ")
                print final_sn
inventory()
```

below are the content of the "inventory.log" file.

```
LAB-SW01#show inventory
NAME: "LAB-SW01", DESCR: "My Switch"
PID: AS-2001-XT   , VID: N/A, SN: ABA0923K0DN
```

When I call the function it doesn't show the result for **final_sn**. I tried to re-order the if statement and it was revealed that it only works for **if** and the first **elif** statement. Do I miss something on my code?

Comment: In the example log file given, your `PID` and `SN` are on the same line. So only the first `elif` gets called. If you want to get both `PID` and `SN` from the same line, you are better off just doing three separate `if` statements.

Comment: Hi, You were right. I tried to modifed the log file, put the SN to the new line and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both `PID` and `SN` on the same line, you only end up running the first `elif` statement.

Try this:

```
def inventory():
with open('inventory.log', 'r+') as f:
    match_hostname = re.compile(r'NAME: "(.+)",')
    match_pid = re.compile(r'PID: (.+) ,')
    match_sn = re.compile(r'SN: (.+)')
    list_text = [text.strip() for text in f]
    for line in list_text:
        match_regex_hostname = match_hostname.search(line)
        match_regex_pid = match_pid.search(line)
        match_regex_sn = match_sn.search(line)
        if match_regex_hostname:
            final_hostname = match_regex_hostname.group(1).strip(" ")
            print final_hostname
        if match_regex_pid:
            final_pid = match_regex_pid.group(1).strip(" ")
            print final_pid
        if match_regex_sn:
            final_sn = match_regex_sn.group(1).strip(" ")
            print final_sn
inventory()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "inventory.log" is a csv file which means that you can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to do this beautifully.

```
def inventory(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print([item.strip()
                   for item in row if item.strip().lower().startswith(('name', 'pid', 'sn'))])
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import io
>>> text = """NAME: "LAB-SW01", DESCR: "My Switch"
... PID: AS-2001-XT   , VID: N/A, SN: ABA0923K0DN"""

>>> with io.StringIO(text) as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     for row in reader:
...         print([item.strip() for item in row if item.strip().lower().startswith(('name', 'pid', 'sn'))])
... 
['NAME: "LAB-SW01"']
['PID: AS-2001-XT', 'SN: ABA0923K0DN']
```